# xbl extends - can't override property

Tags: css, firefox-addon, xbl

I'm trying extend some functionality of colorpicker (chrome://global/content/bindings/colorpicker.xml) which requires modification of color property.
So far I've managed add some content, but property setter not being overrided at all. It seems anything in **implementation** section being ignored

Here is what I have so far:

colorpicker_extended.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
   - License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
   - file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/. -->


<bindings id="colorpickerBindings"
   xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl"
   xmlns:xul="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
   xmlns:xbl="http://www.mozilla.org/xbl">

<!--
  <binding id="colorpicker" extends="chrome://global/content/bindings/general.xml#basecontrol">
-->
  <binding id="colorpicker" extends="chrome://global/content/bindings/colorpicker.xml#colorpicker">
    <implementation implements="nsIDOMEventListener">
      <property name="color">
        <getter><![CDATA[
          return this.mSelectedCell ? this.mSelectedCell.getAttribute("color") : null;
        ]]></getter>
        <setter><![CDATA[
//allow empty value
//but doesn't work
//          if (!val)
//            return val;
          var uppercaseVal = val.toUpperCase();
          // Translate standard HTML color strings:
          if (uppercaseVal[0] != "#") {
            switch (uppercaseVal) {
              case "GREEN":
                uppercaseVal = "#008000";
                break;
              case "LIME":
                uppercaseVal = "#00FF00";
                break;
              case "OLIVE":
                uppercaseVal = "#808000";
                break;
              case "TEAL":
                uppercaseVal = "#008080";
                break;
              case "YELLOW":
                uppercaseVal = "#FFFF00";
                break;
              case "RED":
                uppercaseVal = "#FF0000";
                break;
              case "MAROON":
                uppercaseVal = "#800000";
                break;
              case "PURPLE":
                uppercaseVal = "#800080";
                break;
              case "FUCHSIA":
                uppercaseVal = "#FF00FF";
                break;
              case "NAVY":
                uppercaseVal = "#000080";
                break;
              case "BLUE":
                uppercaseVal = "#0000FF";
                break;
              case "AQUA":
                uppercaseVal = "#00FFFF";
                break;
              case "WHITE":
                uppercaseVal = "#FFFFFF";
                break;
              case "SILVER":
                uppercaseVal = "#C0C0C0";
                break;
              case "GRAY":
                uppercaseVal = "#808080";
                break;
              default: // BLACK
                uppercaseVal = "#000000";
                break;
            }
          }
          var cells = this.mBox.getElementsByAttribute("color", uppercaseVal);
          if (cells.item(0)) {
            this.selectCell(cells[0]);
            this.hoverCell(this.mSelectedCell);
          }
          return val;
        ]]></setter>
      </property>
    </implementation>    
  </binding>

<!--
  <binding id="colorpicker-button" display="xul:menu" role="xul:colorpicker"
           extends="chrome://global/content/bindings/general.xml#basecontrol">
-->
  <binding id="colorpicker-button" display="xul:menu" role="xul:colorpicker"
           extends="chrome://global/content/bindings/colorpicker.xml#colorpicker-button">
  </binding>

  <binding id="extended" extends="chrome://global/content/bindings/colorpicker.xml#colorpicker">
    <content>
      <children/>
      <xul:hbox>
        <xul:spacer class="colorpickertile" color=""/>
      </xul:hbox>
    </content>
  </binding>

</bindings>
```

And colorpicker-exteneded.css:

```
colorpicker
{
    -moz-binding: url("chrome://myextension/skin/colorpicker-extended.xml#colorpicker");
}
colorpicker[type="button"]
{
    -moz-binding: url("chrome://myextension/skin/colorpicker-extended.xml#colorpicker-button");
}
colorpicker > vbox
{
    -moz-binding: url("chrome://myextension/skin/colorpicker-extended.xml#extended");
}
.colorpickertile[color=""],
colorpicker[type="button"][color=""] > hbox
{
    background-image: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAMAAAAoLQ9TAAAABlBMVEXZ3uX///9HjKIIAAAAHElEQVR42mJgBAIGIIDRDGQIkKkNRWCQuAMgwABFEACBx3mMOgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==);
}
```

There is a new "transparent" color added to the table, selecting it works, the button also shows correct "transparent" background, but when colors table opens the transparent color not pre-selected.

From what I could see is that my new "color" property setter is not being used at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: this guy here helped me a lot with xbl, i got no help on stackoverflow, try posting there: https://ask.mozilla.org/question/297/apply-and-remove-xbl-binding-on-runtime/

Comment: I can't find any information regarding this, but someone mention that the probkem I'm having is because I use skin url for .xml And indeed if I change it to content (chrome://example/content/myxbl.xml) then it works fine.

Comment: Yeah i had problem using resource url i had to use chrome to I forgot to mention that to you, thx for reminnder +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out the problem is how the binding is being applied in CSS. You can't use skin url for xbl file:

Bad:

> -moz-binding: url("chrome://myextension/**skin**/colorpicker-extended.xml#colorpicker");

Good:

> -moz-binding: url("chrome://myextension/**content**/colorpicker-extended.xml#colorpicker");

So in my case since I had skin folder inside content all I had to do is change css to this:

```
colorpicker
{
    -moz-binding: url("chrome://myextension/content/skin/colorpicker-extended.xml#colorpicker");
}
colorpicker[type="button"]
{
    -moz-binding: url("chrome://myextension/content/skin/colorpicker-extended.xml#colorpicker-button");
}
colorpicker > vbox
{
    -moz-binding: url("chrome://myextension/content/skin/colorpicker-extended.xml#extended");
}
```